# In RactiveJS how can I detect is it detached?

Tags: javascript, template-engine, ractivejs

I want to

```
if(ractive.isDetached()){
    otherRactive.detach();
    ractive.render().then(()=>ractive.insert());
}
```

Instead of insert and detach every time, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on GitHub – for future travellers, the tl;dr is you can *either* render to a specific target, *or* insert an already-rendered ractive to a new target (detaching it if it's currently in the DOM).

```js
function insertRactive( ractive, node ) {
  if( ractive.fragment.rendered ) ractive.insert( node );
  else ractive.render( node );
}
```

Note that we're determining if an instance is rendered with `ractive.fragment.rendered`, though note that this **isn't officially part of the API** and is therefore subject to change, so it's better to keep track of it yourself.